# Person conducting street shows with monkeys

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a single word for a person who conducts street shows involving monkeys?

Comment: A person with a monkey and a hand-cranked "organ" is an "organ grinder".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Monkey Buskers. Or as a general term you can use "street performer" or "busker". 
Here is some extra information;
[street performer, busker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Street_performance)

The word "Monkey Busker" usage in the news; [Jakarta Monkey Buskers](http://jakartaglobe.beritasatu.com/news/jakarta-begins-crackdown-on-monkey-buskers/)